# How to add Url Parameters in the header

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Following is the Web API Url that I need to call (GET Request) 
https://v-vabhan.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=9,10,11&$expand=all&api-version=2.2

Question -: How to add the 9,10,11 ids in the header???
I want to add this ids in the header

Comment: Could you please update your question to have more information on the context ? Who issues this GET ? Is it from within a web browser , server side code, using some scripting language ?

Comment: You cannot: can you explain why you are asking this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add the work item ids in to the header, otherwise the result is 404.